# Node js couchbase query calls matching with couchbase view

Tags: javascript, node.js, view, couchbase, nosql

I'm having issues passing parameters to a view through the node js couchbase module. The main issue is I don't know what question to ask google in order to get the answer I'm looking for. I would like to get from the view a specific object based on a key that I'm receiving from a UI.

For example, I have a list of stores with store numbers 111, 222, and 333. If the user gives me the store number 222, I'd like to only return that one, instead of return it all then filter inside my node js code.

The node js code looks like this:

```
var query = ViewQuery.from('dev_store', 'store').key(storeNum);
myBucket.query(query, function (err, results) {...};
```

I got that from the `ViewQuery` api mixed with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27742790/couchbase-reduce-by-date-in-node-js). However I cannot figure out how to then access that key parameter once I'm in the view in order to filter down my results to just that one store.

I've tested my view and it works fine, so long as I just get a list of all the stores. I've read about reductions but I haven't seen where those actually get written/called.

I've tried accessing it by doing `doc.key` or adding a key to the view function, but I think my limited understanding of View construction is hurting me here.

**Question**: Given a key, how do I return from a view only the row that pertains to that key?

**EDIT**: Here is my view:

```
function (doc, key,  meta) {
    doc.midLevel.forEach( function ( reg ) {
        reg.midLowerLevel.forEach( function ( dis ) {
            dis.lowestLevel.forEach( function ( store ) {
                emit( store.store_nbr, null);
            })
        })
    })
}
```

In this view it emits every store at the lowest level. As seen in the node js code, I've passed a key to it. I would like to use that key in order to create a condition on what gets emitted.

For example, if there are stores numbered 1-100, and the node js passes the number 45, is it possible for me to access the '45' in the view in order to create that condition statement?

Comment: What is the document's ObjectID? if you had something like store::222 as the objectID for that document, then you just go get that key. No view needed and much faster.

Comment: So the store level would be 3 levels deeper than the root object of the document. Technically an example of objectID for the doc would be a alphabetical letters A-M. So, i'm looking to be able to only emit a particular sub index of the document based off given input. I think this answers your question if not let me know.

Comment: Sorry, I'm reading this comment after posting my answer. What is your document ID? Why are you storing arbitrarily deep objects as single documents as opposed to projecting them into deep objects on the front-end?  Having trouble understanding what to provide as an answer based on the question.

Comment: Full disclosure, this is my first nosql db, and unfortunately they didn't teach nosql in my undergrad. Currently I have a document that represents the highest level with 3 levels beneath it. IE High level has a list of mid levels. Each mid level has a list of low levels. Should I design the db to hold as individual documents all the lower levels and then just have them have references to the high level and take care of that on the front end? Is that proper design?

Comment: Here is a little recommended reading for you to give you a few ideas how you might do access and modeling for Couchbase. http://blog.couchbase.com/2015/october/determine-data-access-in-couchbase and http://blog.couchbase.com/user-profile-store-advanced-data-modeling

Comment: Generally speaking, it is a good idea to develop the data model in a way that mirrors the API. That also means the API should be well-developed. I've found a few good sources there: http://www.vinaysahni.com/best-practices-for-a-pragmatic-restful-api and https://github.com/18F/api-standards

Answer (score 1):

> Question: Given a key, how do I return from a view only the row that pertains to that key?

On the face of it, this question is not relevant to a view.  Views are absolutely not meant to return objects based on the object key. Rather, a view is meant to index **certain properties of stored objects** such that the objects can be pulled together into a list of some sort.

To return a document based on the key, you would perform a simple `get` operation. A view query in this scenario actually degrades performance, since the view must be accessed from disk. An object `get` from a view as opposed to from RAM is an order of magnitude or more slower than a simple read.

Answer: use a `get`, not a view.